# Powershell winforms reference parent in child form

Tags: powershell, winforms, reference, refresh, parent-child

I'm having a difficulty referencing parent form in child form.
I've mocked up a little snippet for this purpose. I know that I have to assign parent property to child form, but I have not had success so far. Please advise

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

#### PARENT FORM

$date = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$date.Text = 'Date'
$date.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(243,230)
$date.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKbutton.Add_Click({$kibel.showdialog()})
$date.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$date_label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$date_label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,70)
$date_label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$date_label.BorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$date_label.Add_Click({$kibel.showdialog()})
$date.Controls.Add($date_label)

##### CHILD FORM

$kibel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$kibel.Text = 'Date'
$kibel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(243,230)
$kibel.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$kibel_texbox= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$kibel_texbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,70)
$kibel_texbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$kibel.Controls.Add($kibel_texbox)

$kibel_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$kibel_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$kibel_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$kibel_button.Text = 'KIBEL'
$kibel_button.Add_Click({$kibel.Parent.Controls['date_label'].Text ='done'})
$kibel.Controls.Add($kibel_button)



$date.ShowDialog()
```

As it is now I am getting `Cannot index into a null array` error

Comment: There's no parent-child relation here. If you set the `IWin32Window` reference in `[Form].ShowDialog([Some Owner])`, then you set the `Owner` (not the `Parent`) but you can use that reference. If / when actually needed.

Comment: You don't need (and cannot) set the parent. Just use the variable that you have defined in the scope: `$kibel_button.Add_Click({$date_label.Text ='done'})`

Comment: The comments came almost at the same time 

Comment: @Jimi I believe that what you propose is currently above my abilities

Comment: @RezaAghaei static assign works fine, thank you. I've managed to assign textbox text to label by using intermedary variable i.e. `$a = textbox.text` `label.text = $a`. Any idea how to skip using variable in this and assign value (text) directly?

Comment: `$kibel_button.Add_Click({$date_label.Text = $kibel_texbox.Text})`

Comment: Had to recheck, as I've tried this before with no result. Maybe misspelled something. Thanks again

Comment: No. it's not, really. But you don't actually need it (as already described). Note that you can also *inject* the `date_label` reference in a Constructor of `$kibel`, since it's the only reference you're using. @RezaAghaei I couldn't hear you typing, I would have waited :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Would you mind pointing me to some reading material about this? Or providing an example based on my little snippet? I like to reverse engineer things

Comment: I just realised I addressed my las comment wrong. Sorry about that @Jimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems you need to address:

- You need to use the `Owner` property to designate the parent/owning form
- You haven't assigned a *name* to the `$date_label` control, so `Controls['date_label']` won't resolve to anything

The first problem can be addressed by assigning the parent form instance to the `Owner` property on the child form:

```
$kibel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$kibel.Text = 'Date'
$kibel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(243,230)
$kibel.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
# designate owning form
$kibel.Owner = $date
```

Then, to name the label, add this after defining `$date_label`:

```
$date_label.Name = 'date_label'
```

And finally, to correctly resolve the control via the parent form, change the `Click` event handler as follows:

```
$kibel_button.Add_Click({$kibel.Owner.Controls['date_label'].Text ='done'})
```